# $PATH doesn't update

Tags: macos, path, terminal

I'm trying to add the folder `~/local/bin` to my `$PATH`, but it does not work. I have tried everything. I have followed every guide on Google and YouTube, I have read dozens of similar questions on StackExchange, I have asked several computer experts I know, I have copied friends' files that works fine for them -- but nothing helps here.

I have tried:

- Adding `~/local/bin` to `/etc/paths`
- Adding the path to both `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`
- Written both `export PATH=$PATH:~/local/bin` and `export PATH="$~/local/bin:$PATH"`
- Both with and without `export`
- Tried with both `~/local/bin`, `/Users/Nachos/local/bin`, and `HOME/local/bin`

I have tried every single possible combination of these, and more. That is, I have tried with just the first thing, then just the second thing, then the first and second thing together, then just the third thing, etc etc. I have literally tried more than 50 different things now, and `echo $PATH`still gives me absolutely nothing but `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`in return.

I have of course also used `source [file]` after every single change, and also tried restarting the terminal after every change. Nothing helps.

This really frustrates me, as I've used a lot of time trying to fix this, and I find very little help about this online, because this apparently shouldn't ever be an issue to anyone. Well, it doesn't work here. Please, someone, help me. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're using is not correct, in `~/.bash_profile` it should be:

```
export PATH="$HOME/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Save the file then do:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

`echo $PATH` should then have output which includes:

```
/Users/Username/local/bin:...
```

***The critical thing is having the correct syntax when adding anything to your profile.***

Comment: I tried too many things to write them all in my original post, and I was sure I tried this aswell. Well, obviously not, because this worked like a charm! Can't believe I missed it. Anyways, thank you so much! :-)